# Making a column immutable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger, constraint

I want to make a column in a relation unmodifyable for consistency reasons.

The backstory is that I have a n:n relationship where the "connecting" relation has additional values. I don't want that anyone is able to change the IDs of the relationship partners.

What I have come up with so far:

Creating a trigger that checks if the NEW value is the same as the OLD value. But I don't know how to deny the UPDATE action if the condition proves as TRUE.

Here is my trigger so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deny_nton_change BEFORE UPDATE ON Schueler_in_Klasse
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.Schueler_ID != OLD.Schueler_ID OR NEW.Klasse_ID != OLD.Klasse_ID THEN

    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than abort the update, just override it?

```
...
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.Schueler_ID = OLD.Schueler_ID;
    SET NEW.Klasse_ID = OLD.Klasse_ID;
END
```

Comment: +1 because this is much simpler than my approach. I am going to look over the MySQL Stored Procedure Language Book (http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596100892) and see it suggests this in the same chapter.

Comment: BTW congrats on 20000 rep and being the first DBA.SE trusted user.

Answer (score 4):

A fairly nice and clean way to abort and return a readable error message is by using a signal:

SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'Schueler_ID and Klasse_ID may not be altered!';

Do make sure your MySQL version supports this, it was introduced in MySQL 5.5. In earlier versions you need hacks like inserting a non existant field into a non existant table.

As gbn mentions, overwriting the new values with the old ones is a good option too.

Comment: As suggested by @RolandoMySQLDBA, this seems to not work... It says there is an error in my SQL syntax

Comment: like I said, check the mysql version. It works on 5.5 fine.

[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)

_To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means “unhandled user-defined exception.”_

Answer (score 2):

[I actually learned a back-alley approach to aborting triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2368/877). It is very crude, but works because SIGNAL processing is not implemented in MySQL's Stored Procedure Language. It can be emulated at best.

Chapter 11, Pages 254-256 of the book **[MySQL Stored Procedure Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892)** under the subheading **'Validating Data with Triggers'** suggests making a SELECT of a character string into a dummy integer (in terms of syntax, it is correct, but dies on execution [NO PUN INTENDED]):

```
CREATE TRIGGER deny_nton_change BEFORE UPDATE ON Schueler_in_Klasse 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE dummy INT; 
    IF NEW.Schueler_ID != OLD.Schueler_ID OR NEW.Klasse_ID != OLD.Klasse_ID THEN 
        SELECT 'Cannot Carry Out This Trigger Any Further'
        INTO dummy FROM table_you_know_does_not_exist WHERE 1=1 LIMIT 1;
    END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: Wow, that is really... Back-alley. Nice one...

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to do this neatly without using triggers if you are using InnoDB.

Create another table with just one column. That column should have a foreign key (hence the innodb requirement in this solution) that points to the immutable column of the original table in question.

Put a restriction like "ON UPDATE RESTRICT".

In summary:

```
CREATE TABLE original (
     ....
     immutable_column ...
     INDEX index1(immutable_column)
     ....
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE restricter (
     .....
     col1,
     INDEX index2(col1),
     FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES original (immutable_colum) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: This looks smart but I see a problem. The column may not be unique (and probably isn't in this case) so a foreign key towards it, is not advised although allowed in MySQL.

Comment: +1 though because if you use the `(Schueler_ID, Klasse_ID)` combination instead of the one column, it should work.

Comment: This should still work even when `immutable_column` is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a combination of all answers I have read this is what worked for me:

```
delimiter $$ -- You may need this or not (in my visual client I need it, directly in console I don't)
create trigger deny_nton_change before update on surveys
for each row begin
    if new.Schueler_ID != old.Schueler_ID OR new.Klasse_ID != old.Klasse_ID then
      signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'My own Error: Field is immutable';
    end if;
end$$
delimiter ; -- You may need this or not
```