# How do I prevent updates on an entire table (but allow inserts) in Mysql 5.5?

Tags: mysql

I want to make the rows in a Mysql table immutable, once they are inserted I don't want it to be possible to change them.  How can I do this?

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8360/making-a-column-immutable-in-mysql) handles making individual rows immutable, but I'm hoping there is a better way to make all rows in a table immutable (ideally returning a suitable error message if any change is attempted).

Answer (score 4):

You can revoke 'UPDATE' privilege for a particular table. Or you can write `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that raises an error (using signals or issuing a statement that always fails).