# MySQL: Try to Port a Trigger from SQL Server

Tags: mysql, trigger

[Here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/), there's a sample of a trigger with "INSTEAD OF UPDATE" clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Test_PTA_Table_Update_trg]
-- ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Test_PTA_Table_Update_trg]
   ON  [dbo].[Test_PTA_Table]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   DECLARE @key int
   SET @key = (SELECT TestTablePK FROM Inserted)

   UPDATE Test_PTA_Table
      SET DateEnd = GetDate(), DateReplaced = GetDate()
      WHERE TestTablePK = @key

   INSERT INTO dbo.Test_PTA_Table
   (TestTableText, DateCreated, DateEffective, OperatorCode, DateReplaced)
   (SELECT TestTableText, GetDate(), GetDate(), OperatorCode, NULL
FROM Inserted)
```

I'm trying to port the principle to MySQL:

```
DELIMITER ;;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS attribut_trigger_update_before;

CREATE TRIGGER attribut_trigger_update_before
BEFORE UPDATE ON attribut
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO attribut SET 
      id_origine      = OLD.id_origine,
      date_v_creation = OLD.date_v_creation,
      date_v_debut    = OLD.date_v_debut,
      date_v_fin      = OLD(),
      importance      = OLD.importance,
      description     = OLD.description,
      valeur          = OLD.valeur,
      abbreviation    = OLD.abbreviation;
  END;;

DELIMITER ;;
```

But it doesn't work.

```
mysql> update produit set importance=3;
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'produit' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
mysql>
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: MySQL does not support `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` triggers. What is the requirement? To keep an audit trail? Inserting into the same table whenever a row in it is updated seems like a strange requirement. Normally you'd audit to a secondary table.

Comment: So, the trigger actually forbids all Updates by converting them to Inserts into the same table?

Comment: You're not allowed to do an insert/update/delete when you're in a trigger of the same table, which is a clear sign that MySQL has still a loooong way to go to catch up with system that do this (SQL server and PostGRESQL). And that is a real problem, I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: @Phil It's not to keep an audit trail, it's to remember *easily* what has been done and to be able to *easily* make request using something like "date of validity" of a product or anything in my database (= generic behavior).

Comment: Two questions: 1) What version of MySQL are you using? 2) What storage engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed before by others

- [Making a column immutable in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8360/making-a-column-immutable-in-mysql)
- [What are some good methods of structuring a MySQL audit trail to be both immutable, and perform well for usage?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9242/what-are-some-good-methods-of-structuring-a-mysql-audit-trail-to-be-both-immutab)

Your question is a little different in this instance. You may have to experiment with `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE` for the desired effect.

You may need to also experiment with disabling the trigger midstream : [Disable trigger for just one table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11046/disable-trigger-for-just-one-table/11055#11055)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the first link is not what I'm looking for (= I don't want to make a column in a relation unmodifyable for consistency reasons), and the second link is about making a separate table for audit trail, which is not what I want. I want to be able to fetch **instantaneously** a product with a specific date of validity (using `date_v_start` and `date_v_end` fields in my sample). So I can't archive, or only log actions: I must have both copies of the same product, before and after the modification.