# MySQL using trigger instead of check

Tags: mysql, trigger

Is there any way that I could use trigger instead of check? like I have

> CREATE
>       /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
>       TRIGGER `test` BEFORE UPDATE ON `apply` 
>       FOR EACH ROW BEGIN      IF NEW.cname = "hi" THEN
>               SET NEW.cname = "hello";
>           ELSE
>               RETURN 1;
>           END IF;
>       END; $$

but return 1 doesn't work. Is there anyway that I can prevent the query from executing?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `RETURN 1` because Trigger is a Stored Procedure, not a Stored Function.

If you want to break it on purpose, that's acceptable.

I wrote two posts about how to break a trigger midstream

- [Trigger in MySQL to prevent insertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/trigger-in-mysql/2371#2371) (Apr 25, 2011)
- [check constraint does not work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work/9668#9668) (Dec 23, 2011)

Try this:

```
CREATE /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */ TRIGGER `test`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `apply` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE dummy INT;

    IF NEW.cname = "hi" THEN          
        SET NEW.cname = "hello";
    ELSE
        SELECT no_such_column INTO dummy
        FROM information_schema.no_such_table;
    END IF;

END; $$
```

Comment: +1. But if it's mysql 5.5 and up, it's probably better to use signals.