# Comparing dates in a BEFORE INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I need help making a `TRIGGER` that compares two dates being entered into a table, but I'm not 100% on the syntax I should use.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER chk_dates
   BEFORE INSERT ON `job_history`
   FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF( NEW.end_date < OLD.start_date ) .../// error, don't insert data
      ELSE .../// allow the data to be entered
```

My table `job_history` will have a `start_date`, and when `end_date` is entered, I want it to check to ensure that it isn't prior to `start_date`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With MySQL 5.5 or 5.6, you can use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) instead of the hacks to bail from a trigger.

Also, on a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, only the `NEW` alias is used.  Not `OLD`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER chk_dates
BEFORE INSERT ON `job_history`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.end_date < NEW.start_date) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'end_date cannot be earlier than start_date';
  END IF;
END;
```

No "else" is needed because taking no action in a `BEFORE` trigger allows the original action to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I am not very proud of what I am about to show you but it must be done

Back on April 25, 2011 I wrote this post : [Trigger in MySQL to prevent insertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/trigger-in-mysql/2371#2371)

It explains how to interrupt a trigger midstream. You do so by deliberately launching an SQL statement that is syntactically correct but breaks on execution. This still was originally suggested on [**pages 254-256 of the book**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892)

[image]

because SIGNAL processing is not properly implemented (OK it wasn't implemented a lick)

With regard to your `something like` code, it should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER chk_dates
   BEFORE INSERT ON `job_history`
   FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      DECLARE x INT;
      IF( NEW.end_date < OLD.start_date ) THEN
          SELECT dummy INTO x FROM mysql.user WHERE 1=1 LIMIT 1;
      ELSE .../// allow the data to be entered
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Very appreciated.