# how to overcome these type of issues where null value inserted into primary key not null column in table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, insert

[image]

how to overcome these type of issues where null value inserted into primary key not null column in table

Comment: You're not inserting a `NULL` value, you're inserting `""`.

Answer (score 1):

As was stated in [the comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90117/how-to-overcome-these-type-of-issues-where-null-value-inserted-into-primary-key#comment161747_90117)

> You're not inserting a NULL value, you're inserting ""

If you want to prevent an empty string ("") and NULLs from being used as `ai_name`, you need a trigger. In your particular case, you need a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER check_for_blank_ai_name
BEFORE INSERT ON actionitems
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE dummy INT;
  IF ( IFNULL(NEW.ai_name,'') = '' ) THEN  
    SELECT 'Any Message' INTO dummy FROM mysql.user WHERE used = 'anything';
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The line of code

```
SELECT 'Any Message' INTO dummy FROM mysql.user WHERE used = 'anything';
```

will break. That's by design. This will prevent the INSERT from occurring.

I have written triggers that break midstream before in my other posts:

- `Jun 09, 2013` : [BEFORE INSERT trigger in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/before-insert-trigger-in-mysql/44140#44140)
- `Dec 11, 2012` : [Comparing dates in a BEFORE INSERT trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30137/comparing-dates-in-a-before-insert-trigger/30138#30138)
- `Dec 23, 2011` : [check constraint does not work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work/9668#9668)
- `Apr 25, 2011` : [Trigger in MySQL to prevent insertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/trigger-in-mysql/2371#2371)

**Give it a Try !!!**