# BEFORE INSERT trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger

I am new to MySQL and I'm having problems creating a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

I get an `unexpected END` error.

I have a table named `verlof_aanvragen` with a column `datum` (and 6 more columns).

What I want to accomplish is only rows with a date between `now()+8` and `now()+365` or  `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 DAY AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 365 DAY)` 
can be inserted. An insert with a date outside that interval should fail.

I am using MySQL version 5.5.24.

This is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER chk_dates  
BEFORE INSERT ON verlof_aanvragen  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
  IF (NEW.datum < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 DAY OR NEW.datum > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 365 DAY) 
THEN  
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Any Message'

END IF  
END
```

Answer (score 5):

I have dealt with this question before. MySQL has a very flimsy architecture when it comes to triggers.

I have written posts before on how to break triggers midstream. The solution is rather unsavory and would leave a pure SQL developer with a bad taste in the month.

With that said, here are my posts that I hope would help:

- `Apr 25, 2011` : [Trigger in MySQL to prevent insertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/trigger-in-mysql/2371#2371)
- `Dec 23, 2011` : [check constraint does not work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work/9668#9668)

Since you are a newbie, writing trigger code requires changing the delimiter to something other than a semicolon and then changing back.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER chk_dates  
BEFORE INSERT ON verlof_aanvragen  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
  IF (NEW.datum < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 DAY OR NEW.datum > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 365 DAY) 
THEN  
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Any Message';
END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Please look back at my posts to see how I do this in my code.

## UPDATE 2013-06-12 11:34 EDT

Here is your last comment

> I am using above trigger with mysql server v 5.5.24 and it works fine.
>   This is my local test site. Now I want to use it at my webhost, they
>   have mysql server v 5.1.56 ... and it won; t work ! Am I missing
>   something?

The problem is the MySQL version. If you look back in my two trigger posts, I used black market techniques to break the trigger midstream. This is necessary for older versions of MySQL. Notice what I stated on `Apr 25, 2011` in [Trigger in MySQL to prevent insertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/trigger-in-mysql/2371#2371) :

> The reason the book suggests preempting the Trigger in this manner
>   stems from the fact that the MySQL Stored Procedure Language did not
>   have SIGNAL implemented into the language (of course, SIGNAL is ANSI
>   standard).
>
> The authors of the book created work arounds by calling on SQL
>   statements that are syntactically correct but fail at runtime. Pages
>   144-145 (Chapter 6: Error Handling) of the book gives these examples
>   on preempting a Stored Procedure directly (Example 6-18) or by SIGNAL
>   emulation (Examples 6-19 and 6-20).

I directly quoted Pages 254-256 of **[the Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892)**

[image: dlckxmd]

Please note the following:

- [MySQL 5.5.8 was released as GA Dec 03, 2010](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-8.html)
- **[The book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892)** was written March 2006

Therefore, *signal processing DOES NOT WORK IN MySQL 5.1*.

You will have to do the following:

- Rewrite the trigger in MySQL 5.1 to break midstream
- The trigger you wrote in the MySQL 5.5 database should stay the way it is now

That's why the trigger does not work in MySQL 5.1.

## UPDATE 2013-06-12 11:44 EDT

Here is what you can do to the trigger in the MySQL 5.1.56 database

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER chk_dates  
BEFORE INSERT ON verlof_aanvragen  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE dummy INT;
  IF (NEW.datum < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 DAY OR NEW.datum > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 365 DAY) 
THEN  
  SELECT 'Any Message' INTO dummy FROM mysql.user WHERE used = 'anything';
END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Since `mysql.user` has no column called `used`, the query does not execute, breaking the trigger.