# Is it possible to prevent an insert without rolling it back?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger

In MySQL 5.5, I know I can prevent an insert by using `SIGNAL`, which rolls back the current transaction of my `INSERT`.

The fact is I want to use a trigger to insert a row in another table, 
but I'd like that to replace the original insertion. If I use `SIGNAL` in the trigger the new insert statement is also cancelled.

*Example:*

If I do

```
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES('a','b');
```

I want to have a new row in a `table_b` but none in the `table_a`.

(I want to replace the original insertion only in a few cases.)

Is it possible in MySQL? 
If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Some things really are better done on application level. I'd say this is one of them.

Comment: @tombom That's probably what we'll do ; I asked that because I like to deal with this kind of things directly in the database, especially in this case where the db is accessed by more than one application. 
This could simplify the queries from the different apps and their maintenance so I thought it'd be worth it to ask.

Comment: Perhaps not necessarily application level. A stored procedure would seem an option to me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not readily availble to provide exact details but I believe 2 more ways are possible:

1. Using blackhole engine on table_a
2. Using proxysql

---

### Using Blackhole engine

It seems to be the simplest solution.

> The BLACKHOLE storage engine acts as a “black hole” that accepts data but throws it away and does not store it.

See [MySQL 5.5 doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) for more details.

First, if you need to keep the `table_a` you need to create a copy of it with the blackhole engine ;

```
CREATE TABLE table_a(
    id    INT unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    field CHAR(5)
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE table_blackhole(
    id    INT unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    field CHAR(5)
)Engine=BLACKHOLE;
```

Then, create the trigger on `table_blackhole`.
Inside the trigger, use

- an `INSERT` on `table_a` (for example) for the normal treatment (we don't prevent the insertion)
- or an `INSERT`on `table_b` for the specific treatment (we "prevent" the normal insertion but there is no rollback).

Instead of inserting rows in `table_a`, do your `INSERT` on `table_blackhole`.

Comment: I really like the blackhole engine approach. 
We have to do a little change in structure (adding a blackhole table on which there'll be the trigger that inserts into A or B) but I think it's the simplest and the more efficient solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Back on `Apr 25, 2011`, I answered the post [Trigger in MySQL to prevent insertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/trigger-in-mysql-to-prevent-insertion/2371#2371)

I learned the technique of making a Stored Procedure abort without SIGNAL from
Chapter 11, Pages 254-256 of the [Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892)

[image: MySQL Stored Procedure Programming]

under the subheading **'Validating Data with Triggers'**

Note what the book (released `April 4, 2006`) says about `SIGNAL`

> The reason the book suggests preempting the Trigger in this manner
>   stems from the fact that the MySQL Stored Procedure Language did not
>   have SIGNAL implemented into the language (of course, SIGNAL is ANSI
>   standard).
>
> The authors of the book created work arounds by calling on SQL
>   statements that are syntactically correct but fail at runtime. Pages
>   144-145 (Chapter 6: Error Handling) of the book gives these examples
>   on preempting a Stored Procedure directly (Example 6-18) or by SIGNAL
>   emulation (Examples 6-19 and 6-20).

An example of how to do this is in  [check constraint does not work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work/9668#9668) (`Dec 23, 2011`)

I have also explained this in my post [BEFORE INSERT trigger in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/before-insert-trigger-in-mysql/44140#44140) (`Jun 09, 2013`)

In your particular case, you need to add the new row to `table_b` and then abort the stored procedure. I cannot guarantee the rollback won't happen but at least no `SIGNAL` should occur. You will have to experiment with this and see.

Comment: I guess it's one thing when you just need to prevent an action, and it's an entirely different matter when you have, say, two actions to deal with, of which one needs to be prevented and the other allowed to perform. Your linked answers clearly have to do with the former issue. They may well be relevant to the latter as well but you didn't test the suggested approach in the OP's scenario. I mean, you could've just commented with a "Related: {link(s) to your answer(s)}" kind of comment with the same effect.

Comment: I tried some things with this idea of abortion procedure but had no chance with it. 
(Also I didn't have much time to test, so maybe I just misunderstood the way to do it)
Anyway I think this shows it is not normally possible to prevent an insert from within a trigger without causing it to roll back. I prefer not to go too deep in workarounds that use MySQL's flaws.
If I'd go for something suggested here, I'd probably chose to do a new table in blackhole engine as suggested by @user1235000

Comment: @CharlOkolms I don't blame you for thinking this way. It is probably better to write INSERTs of this type as a stored procedure rather than a clunky trigger.